# Pop!_OS installer not recognizing partition

Tags: linux, partition, partition-table

I'm trying to configure a dual boot on my PC with Windows 10 and Pop!_OS. So I partitioned my SSD for the Pop!_OS `/boot` (500 MB) and my HD with 100 GB for `/` through Windows 10 partition software:

[image: Screenshot of Windows 10 disk partition software]

But the problem is when I boot my USB Drive with Pop!_OS installer, it doesn't recognize the HD partition. It says it's just a big partition with almost 1 TB and two little ones with Windows metadata and stuff like that.

[image: Screenshot (photograph) of Pop!_OS installer partition screen]

When I tried to look for the partitions through the terminal it showed the same, saying that all the partitions weren't starting on physical sector boundary. 
(I don't know if it makes any difference in this case.) 
Here is partial output from `sudo fdisk -l`:

[image: Screenshot (photograph) of partial output from <code>sudo fdisk -l</code>]

And then I went for Disk Usage Analyzer software available on the Pop!_OS store and it showed only the USB Drive from where I was booting the Pop!_OS for installation and my SSD.

[image: Screenshot of Disk Usage Analyzer]

Comment: I don't know the full answer, but I have an idea. The `fdisk` output says that your 1 TB `sda1` partition is of type "Microsoft LDM data", and your `sda2` partition is of type "Microsoft LDM metadata".  LDM is [Logical Disk Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager).  The "Computer Management" / "Disk Management" (Windows 10 partition software) window shows volumes (partitions) `D:` and `E:` are of type "Dinámico" (Dynamic).  As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager#Overview) says, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  dynamic storage involves the use of a single LDM data partition that covers the entire disk, and that partition is divided into volumes ….   Apparently Linux does not automatically support LDM; see [ldmtool(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ldmtool.1.html) and [this entry in the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_disks) for some information.   Since you don't have any data on the hard disk yet (do I understand that correctly?), the simplest thing to do might be to reformat it and recreate the partitions as basic (not dynamic).

Comment: Thanks, your comments helped me find out the issue!

Comment: Please post an answer describing what you found and what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: Did that just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually the type of partition in my HD that was making it unable to install POP!_OS. I erased all the HD and remade the partitions in GPT. That solved the issue.